# GWT servlet failure with JRE6

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, servlets

A GWT project built with Eclipse Juno and JDK 1.7 works correctly.  However, I have to deploy it to a Tomcat6 server that uses JRE6.  Building it with JDK 1.6 results in a runtime servlet error:

[WARN] failed HttpServlet 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: UriServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

The Eclipse build path libraries are:
  commons-lang3-3.1.jar
  GWT SDK [GWT - 2.5.1]
  JRE System Library [jdk1.6.0_27]

Is there a feature in JDK 1.7 that the servlet needs? Do I have to use an Eclipse version earlier than juno? There has to be a way to build a project than can be deployed to a Tomcat6/JRE6 server.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse, Right now java compiler level may be **1.5**.

You have to change it **1.6** and compile it again.

*Right click project->Properties->Java Compiler->Enable project specific settings*

Comment: This is probably the case. Also check the "Compiler" settings under the project too, there might be "Project Specific Settings" set.

Comment: Thanks! The level was set to 1.7; changing it to 1.6 solved the problem. Just changing the library to jdk1.6 wasn't sufficient.